# "TypeError: 'module' object is not callable" when running tests

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, selenium-webdriver

I'm running the following command from the console

```
$ py.test -m selenium
```

But then I keep getting this error:

```
___________________________________________________ ERROR collecting setup_distribution/verify_distribution_list.py ____________________________________________________
setup_distribution/verify_distribution_list.py:1: in <module>
>   from foodnet.tests.selenium.base import SeleniumFoodnetTestCase
/home/frank/.virtualenvs/foodnet27/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:159: in load_module
>           py.builtin.exec_(co, mod.__dict__)
base.py:8: in <module>
>   class SeleniumFoodnetTestCase(TestCase):
E       TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Below is the code I'm using:

base.py

```
from unittest import TestCase
from foodnet.tests import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, NoAlertPresentException


@selenium
class SeleniumFoodnetTestCase(TestCase):

    superuser_username = 'admin'
    superuser_password = 'some_pwd'
    server_base_url = "http://localhost:8000"

    def setUp(self): # The rest of the code hidden
```

verify_distribution_list.py

```
from foodnet.tests.selenium.base import SeleniumFoodnetTestCase


class CreateDistributionList(SeleniumFoodnetTestCase):

    def test_create_distribution_list(self):
        driver = self.driver
        # The rest of the code hidden for brevity
```

Any ideas why I'm getting the above error?

UPDATE: Below is my directory structure

```
foodnet
|
|- tests
      |
      |- selenium
            |
            |- base.py
            |
            |- setup_distribution
                    |
                    |- verify_distribution_list.py
```

Comment: What is `foodnet.tests.selenium`? Is it a module?

Comment: See my directory structure above.

Comment: Why do you use a package as decorator?